# How do I tell where loot is stored?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Sometimes all the loot is stored in the resource collectors, sometimes the resource collectors are empty and all the loot is in the storage units. Sometimes the Town Hall stores a lot of loot, and sometimes it stores none. Is there a way to tell, before attacking, where the loot is kept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The location of most of the loot can sometimes be hard to be determined. The most visible indications you can use are:

- Collectors (left is full, right is empty)

[image]

[image]

(Notice the small square storage at the top)
[image]

- Storages (from empty to full)

[image][image][image][image]

[image][image][image][image]

Sometimes in the clan castle:

[image]

If none of these appear to have loot, then it will be in the Town Hall.

[I need to resize these >.< will do when I get on my machine]

Answer (score 3):

The only way is to look at the resource collectors to see how full they are as they have different levels of pink liquid in the tube for the elixir collector and a different sized pile of gold in the cart for the gold mine.

I don't believe you can tell how many resources are in a dark elixir drill unfortunately.

Comment: You can definitely tell how much resources are in the dark elixir drill by the square box in the top left

Answer (score 1):

Besides checking the collectors, you can also check the storages, they will have different levels of being filled based on how much loot they have in. This link [here](http://www.clashwiki.com/how-to-tell-if-collectorsstorages-are-full/) has some nice pictures showing the differences. It isn't an exact science, but the general rule is the more filled they look, the more loot will be in them. Also if the person has collected any loot, a portion of it, up to a cap (see [here](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Town_Hall) for a chart) will be stored in the th.