# What do I need to destroy to get all the Dark Elixir in a village?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I want Dark Elixir.

My question is, if it is shown that 1000 Dark Elixir is available as loot in someone's village, and I destroy his storage with lightning spells, will I get all 1000 Dark Elixir, or do I need to destroy the Dark Elixir drills and the Town Hall too in order to get it all?

Comment: "I destroy his storage by lightnings" You can't destroy storages with lightings. They are immune.

Answer (score 5):

As per the [Version 7.156 - 2015-07-01 "Dark Spell Factory" update](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Version_History#Version_7.156_-_1st_July_2015_.22Dark_Spell_Factory.22):

> All resource storages are now immune to all direct spell damage

This means that you will never damage or destroy a Dark Elixir Storage building with lightning spells (or earthquake spells).

As for the other part of your question, the 1000 DE available for loot shown is from all possible sources combined - this includes the DE storage, DE drill(s), Town Hall and the Clan Castle. So yes, you would need to destroy all those buildings to get them all. See [How do I tell where loot is stored?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/250805/4797) - for more info on which buildings are holding the most resources.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get all the dark elixir, you need to destroy the town hall, drills and storage.

The amount of dark elixir you obtain from a storage is 4 times greater than the amount you obtain from the town hall.

The amount of dark elixir you can obtain from a drill is 75% of its current capacity.

So to get a rough estimate of the amount of elixir you can get by destroying the storage, divide the dark elixir amount by 5, then multiply it by 4.

Reference : http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Raids

Answer (score 1):

In order to get all of the Dark Elixir your enemy is holding in their base, you will need to destroy all of the buildings capable of holding Dark Elixir. This includes:

- Town Hall
- Dark Elixir Storage
- Dark Elixir Drill
- Clan Castle

Also, **you cannot use spells on any storages. They are immune as of Version 7.156.**

Answer (score 0):

To get all the dark elixir you have to primarily destroy the dark elixir storage and town hall.The dark elixir drill and the clan castle contain rest of the remaining dark elixir

NOTE Spells do not work on storage but they work on dark elixir drills
If you are having hard time farming dark elixir than reffer [this blog](http://coc11111.blogspot.com/2016/11/dark-elixir-farming-strategies.html)

Answer (score 0):

You first have to study where actually the dark is stored. If you see 1000 dark

- it can be all distributed among storage and drills and th
- it can just be in the drills (dark storage almost empty)
- it can be in storages and th (drills almost empty)

  For that you need to know what full drills look like and how much dark elixir each level of drill stores. You can destroy a dark drill to get the dark in it by using lightning spell on it but you cannot attack a dark elixir storage with a lightning spell. Maybe a skeleton spell will work but you will have to keep the defenses distracted so that they don't attack the skeletons. Else you simply need a strong enough army to destroy the base enough to get the dark stored wherever it is.